# No endpoint listening at local "..."

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have been given a wcf service, and i built a local console applicattion to test it, but i keep getting this error shown in the title. My service runs in the browser as it should, showing the screen where it shows the example and the url where you can test it. Probably the error is in the Web.config or in the App.config. I have this two files:

Web.condig

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  ...
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="RAHPEDWCFService.RAHPEDService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:44184/RAHPEDService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RAHPEDWCFService.IRAHPEDService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRAHPEDService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
          maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
          maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:44184/RAHPEDService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRAHPEDService"
      contract="ServiceReference.IRAHPEDService"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IRAHPEDService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I hope someone could give me a hint.

Comment: The hard time with WCF is reading config files. Harder is reading someone else's. More harder is reading 2 config files.

Comment: Sorry man i get you, but i was hoping someone with experience could easily detect some noob error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to resolve it

1. Please browse your service and click on the Url whether it is showing the metadata or not.
   ex:http: //oj:23/Myservice?wsdl
2. If metadata is not enabled then do the below changes to your service config file.
   i. create a mex endpoint
   ii. Name the service behavior
   Ex:
   < serviceBehaviors>
   < behavior name="SerBehavior">
   < serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
   < /behavior>
   < /serviceBehaviors>
   iii. Add this behavior to your service 
     Ex: 
   < service name="RAHPEDWCFService.RAHPEDService" behaviorConfiguration="SerBehavior">            < /service>
   iv. Build the service and browse click on url to check the metaData
3. In your console application right click on the project and click on Add Service Reference
4. Place the Url in the Address box, click on Go check whether you are able to see the service, select your service and give namespace and click OK
5. create the object of your ServiceClient
6. Call your method

able to see the wsdl metadata in the browser.
If you have multiple endpoints in your client configuration file then you have pass the name of the endpoint to the constructor of ServiceCleint Class

Open Visual studio CommandPrompt and type WcfTestClient, right click on MyServiceProjects, add the service and check whether you are able to add or not and once added call your method under the endpoint appears

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, yeah indeed metadata was not enabled, so i create the things u point out in each step, and the service viewed in the browser didn't throw the metadata enabled error, but in the console application still throws the same error describe in the title of the question.

Comment: can you able to see the wsdl metadata in the browser

Comment: while you adding the service to your console application, can you able to locate the service ?                                                   If yes, please post the client configuration file

Comment: If you have multiple endpoints in your client configuration file then you have pass the name of the endpoint to the constructor of ServiceCleint Class

Comment: Yes im able to see the metadata in the browser, i can find the service when adding the reference, here a link to my http://pastebin.com/t0DQ1rv7, if a created the mex endpoint, should i use a name for the endpoints ? THANKS A LOT =)

Comment: can you show me the code how you r creating the object for serviceClient class

Comment: add this with in service model(<system.serviceModel>) tag                                                                                                                                                                                                         <protocolMapping>
            <remove scheme="http" />
            <add scheme="httpBasic" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
        </protocolMapping>

Comment: I'm creating my serviceClient like this RAHPEDServiceClient client = new RAHPEDServiceClient();

Comment: i added the tags, and the same error is thrown when i tried to run a method from the serivceClass object

Comment: try passing the endpoint name in the constructor of serviceClient class   RAHPEDServiceClient client = new RAHPEDServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IRAHPEDService");

Comment: Oh man it didnt work, im starting to feel a little embarrased Vinod Kumar for taking from you all this time, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: :) if this is a sample project then please share the solution I wil try to resolve and give it back to you. Before that do this                                         i. Open Visual studio CommandPrompt and type WcfTestClient, right click on MyServiceProjects, add the service and check whether you are able to add or not and once added call your method under the endpoint appears

Comment: I added it, thw WCFTestClient says succesfully added service, but the service isn't show on the left panel in the tree view.

Comment: yes then there is a problem with mex endpoint, metadata is not downloading

Comment: please share the service config file, earlier you posted cleint config file

Comment: replace the endpoint points with below script                                                       <endpoint name="hpend" address="http://localhost:8080/RAHPEDService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RAHPEDWCFService.IRAHPEDService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/RAHPEDService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

Comment: run WcfTestClint Again, use this url to add the service                                          http://localhost:8080/RAHPEDService/mex,                                                                 Endpoints are < endpoint name="hpend" address="http://localhost:8080/RAHPEDService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="RAHPEDWCFService.IRAHPEDService"/>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/RAHPEDService/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

Comment: please add the http to url(address), it is missing in the comment

Comment: OH MY GOD! It finally work! man thanks a lot really, i just replace localhost:8080 with localhost:44184 cause is the port where i runnning the service, really man thanks a lot

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MmfNhryt           this is not entire config file, this is just System.serviceModel  script

Comment: port is not the problem, the problem is you dont have a base address of endpoints and we have given the mex endpoint address as mex, because of this it was not working, now we have added the complete url for mex endpoint so it is downloading the metadata :), it will work well in the console application also try it and please mark this as answer :) good night its already late night for me byebye

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you are accessing the correct address. Rather than specify the entire address in the Web.config, more common practice is to provide just a relative address (even 
an empty "" is fine), and then you access the service with:

```
http://servername:[port]/[virtual directory]/RAHPEDWCF.svc/[relative address in Web.config]
```

E.g. if address in Web.config showed

```
endpoint address="MySVC"
```

the full URL for clients (assuming default port 80 and in root of virtual server) might be

```
http://servername/RAHPEDWCF.svc/MySVC
```

If you are able to modify Web.config, this is what I would advise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i try putting in the Web.config file the address field like, address="", address="http://localhost:44184/", and i leave the address in the console application with the full URI, with no success.